# CiviCase and Drupal Webforms

Tags: webform-civicrm, civicase, checksum

Kind of related to my last question earlier today, I'd like to send a link to someone who has completed a webform but does not have a user account, and ask them to make changes/improve their responses on the webform. On the webform, there are two contacts (both individuals, with a relationship between the two) and one Case.

If I'm logged in and use the url: https://mysite.org/individual-grant/?cid2=2&cid1=27&caseid=12 this populates the webform with the correct information, so I know the syntax here is OK.

My issue is trying to get it working with a checksum token. I can't tell if it's the webform/url that's the problem, or the checksum itself.